# Determine whether the locus of the point P will intersect the straight line $y=-1$

Tags: geometry

A point $P(x,y)$ moves in such a way that its distance from the point $A(3,1)$ is always three times its distance from the straight line $x=-1$.

(a) Find the equation of the locus of the moving point P.

(b) Determine whether the locus of the point P will intersect the straight line $y=-1$.

I have solved (a) but was unable to solve (b). I have tried to substitute $y=-1$ into the locus equation.

Comment: on the line $y=-1$, $x$ is zero so put $x=0,y=-1$ in the equation of locus, if this point satisfies the equation then Locus will intersect the line $y=-1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) The distance of the point $P(x, y)$ from the point $A(3, 1)$  is such that $$\sqrt{(x-3)^2+(y-1)^2}=3\times \frac{|x+1|}{\sqrt{1^2+(0)^2}}$$
$$(x-3)^2+(y-1)^2=9(x+1)^2$$
$$x^2-6x+9+y^2-2y+1=9(x^2+2x+1)$$
$$8x^2-y^2+24x+2y-1=0$$ 
$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{\text{equation of the locus of point P:}\ 8x^2-y^2+24x+2y-1=0}}$$

Above is the locus of the point $P(x, y)$

b) setting $y=-1$ in the above equation, we get   $$8x^2-(-1)^2+24x+2(-1)-1=0$$
$$2x^2+6x-1=0$$ Checking the nature of roots of above quadratic equation by using discriminant $\Delta$, as follows 
$$\Delta=B^2-AC=(6)^2-4(2)(-1)=44>0$$ Above positive value of the discriminant shows that there are two distinct real roots i.e. the locus of the point P intersects the straight line: $y=-1$ at two different points .

Comment: Can this be done using b2-4ac?

Comment: No need to calculate the discrimant: it is positive since the additive constant is negative.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right